# Why does in a regular expression \zs \ze cause "E486: Pattern not found"?

Tags: regular-expression

I want to find and eventually delete all whitespace between all occurrences of an equal sign and the next character. For example, turn

```
@article{article1,
  author=       {author1},
  journal=      {journal1},
  year=         2022,
}
@article{article2,
  author=       {author2},
  journal=      {journal2},
  year=         2022,
}
```

into

```
@article{article1,
  author={author1},
  journal={journal1},
  year=2022,
}
@article{article2,
  author={author2},
  journal={journal2},
  year=2022,
}
```

I tried to do this in vim with the following regex

```
:s/=\zs\s\+\ze.//
```

However, an error message is returned:

```
E486: Pattern not found: =\zs\s\+\ze.
```

even though all the desired occurrences are highlighted correctly.

Does someone know, what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You can also do it by `:%s/=\s\+/=/g`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is that you do not use a range with `:s`, which means it will only act on the *current* line. But you regex is also more complicated than necessary. This should work:

```
:%s/=\zs\s\+//
```

Answer (score 2):

> I want to find and eventually delete all whitespace between all occurrences of an equal sign and the next character.

...

With

```
:s/=\zs\s\+\ze.//
```

you do substitute *on a current line*.

Add range to your substitution, all buffer lines `%` (check `:h :range`)

```
:%s/=\zs\s\+\ze.//
```